# Does a deleted answer increase the minimum bounty amount?

Tags: support, bounty, deleted-answers

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263561/qt-android-virtual-keyboard-keeps-switching-to-uppercase-when-i-type-in-a-qline) where I wanted to start a bounty. I see the minimum is 200 points.

The question has no answers except a single deleted one. It really should have been a comment, and it was changed to a comment after I flagged it as "Not an answer".

Does a deleted answer affect the minimum bounty amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You posted a 100 point bounty on that question before, so your new bounty has to be double that at minimum. See the [post revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25263561/revisions).

The deleted answer had no influence here.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't remember the bounty actually, I must have posted it a while ago and totally forgot about it. And because I didn't see anything in the question itself, I didn't realize I had posted a bounty before. So a deleted answer does not affect the minimum bounty at all?

Comment: @sashoalm: nope. Only previously posted bounties do.

Comment: deleted answer having no influence opens an interesting opportunity to abuse the system: 1) delete answer 2) start bounty 3) undelete answer 4) profit

Comment: @gnat: you mean if the system disregarded past bounties if they were awarded to a deleted answer? Because it doesn't take bounty awards into account; the previous bounty here was never even awarded..

Comment: no. I think I misread the question here. I thought it's about giving bounty to a question with own answer ([which doubles minimum value](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/165773)) - without 10K I could not see who wrote that deleted answer